# How can I clone a repository from Github, and then install the dependencies without error?

Tags: npm, dependencies, hardhat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4I9V.png)

Hello everybody. I have a problem regarding npm installing. I wanna clone a repository from a Github account. After cloning the repo and navigating to the folder, I run "npm install" to install the dependencies but I get this kind of error (the screenshot above). How can I fix this error? Thank you.

My purpose is to install the dependencies, and then compiling the smart contracts.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you actually go inside the directory you're cloning. Do `cd hardhat-fund-me-fcc` and then do again `npm install`